# Easiest way to create horizontal scroll page without reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a task to create horizontal scroll website without page reloading when click on menu links.

Example what I need to create is something like this http://www.rezo-zero.com or http://www.dasselundwagner.com/en Except that my project is much more simpler but main idea how it should work is same as in that examples.

So, maybe you have any suggestions what is the best way to create project like that? Or maybe you know any wireframes?

Or maybe there is wordpress theme which work this way and I could adopt it to my project?

I just need main principles how it works and what I need to use it to make it.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. They all have their pros and cons. Tell us what you tried if you want some help.

Comment: I tried to use this plugin http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ but I don't think it is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Parallax Scrolling".

Using this term, you can find multiple libraries that make it easy.

Some examples :

- [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)
- [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
- [Jarallax](http://www.jarallax.com/demo/)
- [10 Best Parallax Scrolling Plugins](http://beebom.com/2015/04/best-parallax-scrolling-plugins)